# Spark Scala column cannot be resolved in join

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to join two tables. Both include the column 'joindate'. I doublecheck by printSchema and selecting on that column, which works perfectly.

The second I'm trying to join the tables I get the following exception:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: USING column `joindate` cannot
>   be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: [...]

All columns are included in [...] except 'joindate'. How can that happen?

If I do a selfjoin on the left column on 'joindate' it works perfectly fine. A selfjoin on the right column on 'joindate' does also work:

```
left.select("joindate").filter($"joindate" === "2017-12-27").distinct.join(left.select("joindate").filter($"joindate" === "2017-12-27").distinct ,Seq("joindate") ,"inner").show
```

I tried string and date as types for 'joindate'.

Unfortunately I cant reproduce an example nor share my code.

Comment: I once had a similar issue, the solution was to do `df.select($"joindate".as("joindate"))` before the join

Comment: I would not recommend to have both of your join columns named the same  i.e right Joindate and Left Joindate.  rename the left column before join with .WithColumnRenamed("Joindate", "Left_joindate").  do a print Schema of both tables and then use the new  left_joindate.  reason for not having the same column names is in case of nulls  it would not know what values to pick if you are doing a fullouter join. and hence most of the records will have nulls. which is the issue I had faced.

Comment: also  I see that you are using Seq("joindate") for your left where is that coming from? as I don't see a left dataframe in your snippet